# Correct usage of PHP library - GeoPattern

Tags: php, svg

I needed random patterns as background images for my site. I found this awesome php library known as [geopattern](https://github.com/redeyeventures/geopattern-php). Here are some [beautiful examples](https://github.com/explore). The usage seemed pretty straightforward so I set up a test. Here is the code in my test.php.

```
require_once('geopattern_loader.php');
$geopattern = new \RedeyeVentures\GeoPattern\GeoPattern();
$geopattern->setString('Mastering Markdown');
$geopattern->setBaseColor('#54ff9f');
$geopattern->setColor('#ffff00');
$geopattern->setGenerator('sine_waves');
$svg = $geopattern->toSVG();
$base64 = $geopattern->toBase64();
$dataURL = $geopattern->toDataURL();
```

I am trying to display a pattern with a code below. But somehow I am not able to get the image to display in the frontend.

```
echo '<div style="background-size: 400px 400px; height: 400px; width: 400px; background-image: '.$dataURL.';"></div>';
```

---

Here is what it looks like in the [view-source](http://pastebin.com/1S2fxaBS) and Here is [link to result of](http://pastebin.com/XYzcZb20) `echo $dataURL`. You may notice that the string is unusually long. Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

---

**UPDATE** : Here is what my html and css looks like.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
<head><meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type"></head>
<body>
<?php echo '<div style="background-size: 400px 400px; height: 400px; width: 400px; background-image: '.$dataURL.';"></div>'; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Here is how it looks in the firebug css console.

```
element.style {
    background-image: url("");
    background-size: 400px 400px;
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
}
```

Comment: The code you gave is fine. The Base64 image you linked to works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/f24jbjqb/ the issue is something related to your HTML/CSS. Maybe you should post more of the HTML/CSS and add those as tags on your question.

Comment: @Adelphia I have updated the question please check. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I gave you the answer, please accept my answer to get your points and upvote if it helps :) Godspeed.

Comment: cant believe I missed something so elementary. Time to take a break I guess. Thnx for the help. Upvoted :)

Comment: It happens. 90% of the questions I ask on here are just like this lol...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the quotes. Your Base64 image uses double quotes, effectively closing the "style" attribute on your div.

You'll have to use single quotes on your style attribute and escape them like this:

```
<?php echo '<div style=\'background-size: 400px 400px; height: 400px; width: 400px; background-image: '.$dataURL.';\'></div>'; ?>
```